# Response laravel 4.2 shows key:value and index:value from DB query

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent, response, laravel-4.2

I have code like this

```
$idUser = Input::get('idUser');
$user = User::where('id', $idUser)
        ->first();

return Response::json($user, 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

and shows as following

```
{
    "id": 22941,
    "0": 22941,
    "name": "Thanos",
    "1": "Thanos",
    "lastname": "El titan",
    "2": "El titan"
}
```

This only happens in local enviroment.
I don't know if I have to change any config or what am I doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not confident how Laravel 4.2 handles things. Could you check out what `return Response::json($user->toJson(), 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);` does here?

Comment: @RobinMartijn return `{\"id\":22941,\"0\":22941,\"name\":\"Thanos\",\"1\":\"Thanos\",\"lastname\":\"El titan\",\"2\":\"El titan\"}`